# Remove repeating numbers from for loop

Tags: r, recursion, mathematical-optimization, subset-sum, bin-packing

I have the following code in R (published by Mark - [Finding all possible combinations of numbers to reach a given sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632322/finding-all-possible-combinations-of-numbers-to-reach-a-given-sum)) that allows me to add numbers upto the target value.
However, I want the code to return all possible combinations without repeating the same numbers and also store the removed numbers in a separate list. Do I need to assign index values?

```
x <- c(55,10,13,26,34,72,51,96,13)

subset_sum = function(numbers,target,partial=0){
  if(any(is.na(partial))) return()
  s = sum(partial)
  if(s > target) return()
  if(between(s,target-3,target)) print(sprintf("%s = %s",paste(partial[-1],collapse=" "),s))
  for(i in seq_along(numbers)){
      n = numbers[i]
      remaining = numbers[(i+1):length(numbers)]
      subset_sum(remaining,target,c(partial,n))
    }
}

subset_sum(x,60)

#The actual output is:
[1] "10 13 34 = 57"
[1] "26 34 = 60"

#I expect the output as (no repetition of 34):
[1] 26 34 = 60
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Without number repetition, this becomes very similar to bin packing problem. Looking into that might help.

Comment: @Shree: Thank you for the guidance, I will look into it!

Answer (score 0):

The package `RcppAlgos` (I am the author) was built specifically for this task. Below is a solution that utilizes `comboGeneral` which is used to generate combinations with or without repetition as well as of multisets. We can also constrain the output with the use of `constraintFun`, `comparisonFun`, and `limitConstraints`:

```
library(RcppAlgos)
mySubsetSum <- function(x, myTarget, repeats = FALSE) {
    if (0 %in% x)
        x <- x[-which(x == 0)]

    if (repeats) {
        tbl <- table(x)
        vals <- as.numeric(names(tbl))
        myfreqs <- unname(tbl)
    } else {
        vals <- unique(x)
        myfreqs <- rep(1, length(vals))
    }

    ## Add zero length(vals) - 1 times
    myfreqs <- c(length(vals) - 1, myfreqs)
    vals <- c(0L, vals)

    combs <- comboGeneral(vals, length(vals), freqs = myfreqs, 
                          constraintFun = "sum", 
                          comparisonFun = "==", 
                          limitConstraints = myTarget)

    lapply(1:nrow(combs), function(x) combs[x, combs[x,] != 0])
}

mySubsetSum(x, 60)
[[1]]
[1] 26 34

mySubsetSum(x, 60, TRUE)
[[1]]
[1] 26 34

[[2]]
[1] 13 13 34
```

It is written in `C++` for maximum speed. Here is an example demonstrating it's efficiency:

```
set.seed(42)
s <- sample(-50:50, 20)
s
[1]  42  43 -22  31  12  -1  19 -38  11  14  -9  41  33 -28 -10  30  38 -41 -11  -5

system.time(bigTest <- mySubsetSum(s, 170))
 user  system elapsed 
0.039   0.000   0.040

length(bigTest)
[1] 2135

## Over 1 million total combinations
comboCount(c(0, s), 20, freqs = c(19, rep(1, 20)))
[1] 1048575
```

Here is a sample of the output from `bigTest`

```
bigTest[1:5]
[[1]]
[1] -41 -38 -28 -22 -10  -5  11  12  14  19  30  31  33  38  41  42  43

[[2]]
[1] -41 -38 -28 -22  -9  -5  -1  11  12  14  19  30  31  33  38  41  42  43

[[3]]
[1] -41 -38 -28 -22  -1  11  12  19  30  31  33  38  41  42  43

[[4]]
[1] -41 -38 -28 -11 -10  -5  12  14  19  30  31  33  38  41  42  43

[[5]]
[1] -41 -38 -28 -11  -9  -5  -1  12  14  19  30  31  33  38  41  42  43

## View the last 5 combinations
bigTest[length(bigTest) - 4:0]
[[1]]
[1] 12 14 31 33 38 42

[[2]]
[1] 14 19 30 31 33 43

[[3]]
[1] 11 12 14 19 30 41 43

[[4]]
[1] 11 12 14 19 31 41 42

[[5]]
[1] 11 12 14 19 33 38 43


all(sapply(bigTest, sum) == 170)
[1] TRUE
```

You can also find combinations that have a sum between a range. It looks like the OP has this mind originally as the OP makes use of `between` from `dplyr` (at least I think it is from `dplyr`).

```
sumRange <- comboGeneral(c(0, s), 20, freqs = c(19, rep(1, 20)), 
                         constraintFun = "sum", 
                         comparisonFun = c(">", "<"), 
                         limitConstraints = c(155, 165))

all(rowSums(sumRange) > 155 & rowSums(sumRange) < 165)
[1] TRUE
```